# C++ multiple inheritance resolution issue with Visual Studio 2010 results in C2509 error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, multiple-inheritance

I'm trying to do something like C# explicit interface implementation in unmanaged C++.  I am able to do it so long as the function implementation is part of the class definition but I can't figure out how to get it to work with the function implementation in the source file.

Here's my test code:

```
class Base
{
public:

    virtual void    Func() = 0;

    void    CallFunc()
    {
        Func();
    }
};

class Base1 : public Base
{
public:

    virtual void    Func() = 0;
};

class Base2 : public Base
{
public:

    virtual void    Func() = 0;
};

// This Works

class Multi : public Base1, public Base2
{
public:

    virtual void    Base1::Func()
    {
        puts("Base1::Func()");
    }

    virtual void    Base2::Func()
    {
        puts("Base2::Func()");
    }
};


// This does not

//  1>multipeinheritancetest.cpp(60): error C2509: 'Func' : member function not declared in 'Multi'
//  1>          multipeinheritancetest.cpp(51) : see declaration of 'Multi'
//  1>multipeinheritancetest.cpp(65): error C2509: 'Func' : member function not declared in 'Multi'
//  1>          multipeinheritancetest.cpp(51) : see declaration of 'Multi'
/*
class Multi : public Base1, public Base2
{
public:

    virtual void    Base1::Func();
    virtual void    Base2::Func();
};

void Multi::Base1::Func()
{
    puts("Base1::Func()");
}

void Multi::Base2::Func()
{
    puts("Base2::Func()");
}
*/

// This is a work-around for when I don't want to declare the full function in the header
/*
class Multi : public Base1, public Base2
{
public:

    virtual void    Base1::Func() { Base1_Func(); }
    virtual void    Base2::Func() { Base2_Func(); }

    void    Base1_Func();
    void    Base2_Func();
};

void Multi::Base1_Func()
{
    puts("Base1_Func()");
}

void Multi::Base2_Func()
{
    puts("Base2_Func()");
}
*/

void RunMultiTest()
{
    Multi m;
    m.Base1::CallFunc();
    m.Base2::CallFunc();
}
```

Is there a way to do this and my syntax is just off or is this a Visual Studio bug or is this just not possible with C++?

Comment: The issue is how to define `Base1::Func` outside of the class.  The working example uses inline code inside the class.

Answer (score 2):

The `Base1::Func` isn't valid in your "works" case either, it's just accepted by your compiler.

If you want two different functions *call them two different names*. If you want one function, use virtual inheritance:

EDIT: fixed from comment
`class Base1 : public virtual Base`
and
`class Base2 : public virtual Base`

and then remove the base qualification from the function override.

Comment: If virtual inheritance is the desired solution, the virtual keyword belongs on Base1 and Base2 (i.e. "class Base1 : public virtual Base" and "class Base2 : public virtual Base".

Comment: And if you can't change the names (third-party classes), introduce another layer of inheritance which is simply a renaming shim.